# How do I paste a raw image from the clipboard into Emacs?

Tags: windows, emacs, org-mode

I am a Microsoft OneNote user and I have got used to taking a lot of snapshots and embedding them into my notes.

I think that if I could easily embed images directly into Emacs/orgmode from clipboard, then I will be able to switch to Emacs very easily. How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 3):

See [lists.gnu](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-07/msg01292.html) for the windows answer. If you add [hotkey for snipping tool](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/hot-key-for-snipping-tool-in-windows7/7fbbd177-c105-4dc4-b16f-caafcf69b0e7) and use a modified version where you call 'org-mode just before org-display-inline-images like this

```
(funcall 'org-mode)
(org-display-inline-images))
```

and add F4 as hot key for the function in emacs

```
(global-set-key [f5] 'org-screenshot)
```

then you can copy paste with just F4, F5 which is pretty handy. The only problem is that your buffer needs to be saved to a file before the function will work, otherwise you get a array-null-p error because of the call to buffer-file-name

Answer (score 2):

There is a small [tip on Worg](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html#sec-3-8) dealing with this issue. However this solution uses the ImageMagick library. I am not sure this is available on Windows. Maybe you can adapt this and find a solution that fits your need.

Comment: Not sure why an Emacs question was moved from SO to SU though.

Answer (score 1):

I write an extension named "pasteex-mode", it may help you :)

You can just use one key to save clipboard image to disk file, and at the same time insert the file link(org-mode/markdown-mode) or file path(other mode) to current point.

link: [pasteex-mode](https://github.com/dnxbjyj/pasteex-mode)